# How to stop a jQuery called php function when user clicks link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to call php functions.  This works fine except that when a user clicks on a link (if the PHP function hasn't completed executing), the new page will not start loading until the PHP function finishes.

Is there a setting in jQuery I need to change?

Comment: Usually this should not happen if you did not set async to false when calling ajax().
Maybe you can tell us some more or show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using session handling in your PHP code?

If 2 PHP processes are running using the same session, one process will block (wait) until the second one finishes.

Try calling session_write_close() as soon as possible to prevent this from happening.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php for more details.

Comment: Interesting I never thought of this. I imagine you could break this with a custom session handler given the right use case.

Comment: Interesting I never thought of this. I imagine you could break this with a custom session handler given the right use case.